# SQL Results to XML

Tags: sql-server, xml, formatting

When I run the below query:

```
SELECT c.FirstName
FROM HumanResources.Employee e
INNER JOIN Person.Contact c 
    ON c.ContactID = e.ContactID
WHERE c.FirstName = 'Rob'
FOR XML RAW ('Employee');
```

I get the following result:

```
<Employee FirstName="Rob"/>
```

I'm wondering is there a way that I can format it like below:

```
<Employee>Rob<Employee/>
```

Comment: What does `SELECT @@version;` return?

Comment: It seems that you are using MS SQL Server. Please confirm

Comment: Hi guys, thanks forgetting back to me. Looks like its Microsoft SQL Azure(RTM) Im using

Answer (score 1):

Use `FOR XML PATH` instead of `FOR XML RAW` [reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/xml/for-xml-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver16)

```
SELECT c.FirstName Employee
FROM (
    VALUES ('Rob'), ('Bob')
) c (FirstName)
FOR XML PATH ('');
```

Returns:

| Result |
| --- |
| <Employee>Rob</Employee><Employee>Bob</Employee> |

Comment: You can also use elements option to convert them into element centric style:
...FOR XML RAW ('Employee'), ELEMENTS